# не срабатывает OnDestroyView для дважды вложенных фрагментов

Tags: android, kotlin, android-navigation-view

Я пробился над проблемой 2 дня и так и не нашел грамотного решения (только костыльное получил). Суть проблемы:

У нас есть фрагмент А. Внутри фрагмента А есть FrameLayout, который в какой-то момент заменяется на фрагмент B1(либо B2). Далее, для плавной отработки анимации я вынес тяжелый кусок (с youtube api) в еще один фрагмент С. Таким образом, мы получаем слоеный пирог: Внутри А FrameLayout заменяется на фрагмента B, а внутри B FrameLayout заменяется на фрагмент C.  Так вот, при смене фрагмента B1 на B2, OnDestroyView срабатывает только для B1, а вот для C не срабатывает. Т.к. я использую одни и те же фрагменты (не создаю их каждый раз для быстрой работы приложения), у меня нарушается логика.

Для замены внутреннего фрагмента, я использую примерно следующую функцию:

```
inline fun <reified T : Fragment> replaceFragment(
        tag: String = T::class.java.name,
        addToBackStack: Boolean = true,
        @IdRes containerId: Int = R.id.mainContainer,
        animationType: AnimationType = AnimationType.WITHOUT,
        arguments: Bundle? = null,
        crossinline newInstance: () -> T
) {

    fragmentManager?.apply {
        beginTransaction().apply {
            setCustomAnimation(animationType)
            val d = findFragmentByTag(tag) ?: newInstance.invoke()
            arguments?.let { d.arguments = it }
            replace(containerId, d , tag)
            if (addToBackStack) {
                addToBackStack(tag)
            }
            setReorderingAllowed(true)
            commitAllowingStateLoss()
        }
    }
}
```

Использую так:

```
replaceFragment(containerId = R.id.middleContainer, animationType = AnimationType.FADE_IN) { StubFragment() }
```

Суть в следующем: если в памяти был найден фрагмент с данным тэгом, то взять его и не создавать новый. Проблему я описал выше.

Костыль, который почему-то работает:
Если разорвать цепочку за счет промежуточного фрагмента, который инициализирован напрямую в xml, то onDestroyView начинает работать, но как вы понимаете, это громоздко. Хотелось бы понять, почему onDestroyView не вызывается для крайнего фрагмента? Мб у меня ошибка в функции? Никак не могу в этом разобраться.

Comment: Парни из Гугла на каком-то из IO рассказывали, что такие "пироги" могут не работать и никто с этим ничего не будет делать. Совет простой -- упрощайте.

Comment: ну хоть кто-то что-то сказал) спасибо, подумаю как сделать иначе.